# Splunk chart function displaying zero values when trying to round off input

Tags: splunk

I have been trying to display a chart in splunk. I uploaded my json data through Splunk HTTP Forwarder and running the query:

After I uploaded the json data, I have got fields such as

```
"message":{"acplbuild":"ACPL 1.20.1","coresyncbuild":"4.3.10.25","testregion":"EU_Stage","client":"EU_Mac","date":"2019-08-27","iteration":"20","localCreateTime":"6.672","createSyncTime":"135.768","createSearchTime":"0.679","filetype":"CPSD","filesize":"690_MB","filename":"690MB_NissPoetry.cpsd","operation":"upload","upload_DcxTime":"133.196","upload_manifest_time":"133.141","upload_journal_time":"1.753","upload_coresync_time":"135.225","upload_total_time":142.44},"severity":"info"}
```

I am trying to run the following query

```
index="coresync-ue1" host="acpsync_allacpl_7" message.testregion=EU_STAGE message.client=EU_Mac message.operation="upload"  |eval roundVal = round(message.upload_total_time, 2) | chart median(roundVal) by message.acplbuild
```

I am getting no values. It should display rounded off median values as a chart. Can someone point me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: The typical way to debug queries that display nothing is to iteratively drop commands until events are displayed again.  The last command dropped is the one with the problem.  In this case, I believe you need an `spath` command before you can reference 'message.testregion'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the same data as specified by you and I faced an issue while rounding off the upload_total_time value. So, I first converted it to number, and then the Splunk search query worked.

**Input Data Set**

```
{"message":{"acplbuild":"ACPL 1.20.1","coresyncbuild":"4.3.10.25","testregion":"EU_Stage","client":"EU_Mac","date":"2019-08-27","iteration":"20","localCreateTime":"6.672","createSyncTime":"135.768","createSearchTime":"0.679","filetype":"CPSD","filesize":"690_MB","filename":"690MB_NissPoetry.cpsd","operation":"upload","upload_DcxTime":"133.196","upload_manifest_time":"133.141","upload_journal_time":"1.753","upload_coresync_time":"135.225","upload_total_time":142.44},"severity":"info"}
{ "message":{"acplbuild":"ACPL 1.20.2","coresyncbuild":"4.3.10.25","testregion":"EU_Stage","client":"EU_Mac","date":"2019-08-27","iteration":"20","localCreateTime":"6.672","createSyncTime":"135.768","createSearchTime":"0.679","filetype":"CPSD","filesize":"690_MB","filename":"690MB_NissPoetry.cpsd","operation":"upload","upload_DcxTime":"133.196","upload_manifest_time":"133.141","upload_journal_time":"1.753","upload_coresync_time":"135.225","upload_total_time":152.44123},"severity":"info"}
{ "message":{"acplbuild":"ACPL 1.20.3","coresyncbuild":"4.3.10.25","testregion":"EU_Stage","client":"EU_Mac","date":"2019-08-27","iteration":"20","localCreateTime":"6.672","createSyncTime":"135.768","createSearchTime":"0.679","filetype":"CPSD","filesize":"690_MB","filename":"690MB_NissPoetry.cpsd","operation":"upload","upload_DcxTime":"133.196","upload_manifest_time":"133.141","upload_journal_time":"1.753","upload_coresync_time":"135.225","upload_total_time":160.456},"severity":"info"}
```

**Splunk Search Query**

```
source="sample.json" index="splunk_answers" sourcetype="_json"
| convert num(message.upload_total_time) as total_upld_time
| eval roundVal = round(total_upld_time,2)
| chart median(roundVal) by message.acplbuild
```

**Statistics View**

[image]
**Visualization View**

[image]